# Change label to integer using string with format

Tags: ios, objective-c, stringwithformat

I want that every time a user clicks a button the number inside of it increases by 1. Below is the code to do that which works fine. However i want it to be in brackets e.g (1) when they press the button changes to (2) etc. How do i do this? 
Thanks

```
-(IBAction)passButton:(id)sender{
passCounter = passCounter + 1;
passLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",passCounter];   
}
```

Comment: You better learn some basics in `Objective C`. try `passLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%i)",passCounter];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)passButton:(id)sender{
   passCounter++;
   passLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%i)",passCounter];   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
passLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%i)",passCounter];
```